# Minimal non-nilpotent group (characterization)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$=$P$$\rtimes$$\langle$$x$$\rangle$ a finite group where $P$ denotes a normal $p$-group, $\langle$$x$$\rangle$ is a cyclic $q$-group (p,q distinct primes) |$\langle$$x$$\rangle$|=$q^b$ but $x^q$$\in$$Z(G)$.
Why can't I conclude that $G$ is a minimal non nilpotent group? 
The condition $x^q$$\in$$Z(G)$ guarantees that every proprer subgroup is direct product of its Sylow's subgroups. Isn't it? Where is my mistake?
Thank you very much for every kind of suggestion!

Comment: "Minimal nilpotent group"...in **what family** of groups?? For one, $\;P\le G\;$ is nilpotent, too...

Comment: @DonAntonio Excuse me for the mistake: $G$ is not nilpotent but every proper non trivial subgroup is nilpotent.

Comment: The could be a non-nilpotent subgroup of the form $Q \rtimes \langle x \rangle$ for some $Q < P$.

Comment: @DerekHolt That's right! Sorry for the stupid question. Thank you very much for the help!